# LDAPMODIFY - LDIF format for modifying DNs of computer objects

Tags: ldap

I'd like to write a `ldapmodify` command and pass in a ldif file to move computers to a new OU. This means I need to change the DNs.

Example:

CN=joesworkstation,OU=training,OU=computers,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com

to

CN=joesworkstation,OU=laptops,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com

The `man ldif` shows how to rename a CN for a user, but not changing a DN for a computer. Based on their example though, this is my ldif file format guess:

```
dn: CN=joesworkstation,OU=training,OU=computers,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com
changetype: modify
replace: dn
dn: CN=joesworkstation,OU=laptops,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com
deleteoldrdn: 1
```

Is this the most correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a solution to work finally today. 
To update the DN of computer objects I used the following LDIF formatted file:

```
dn: CN=joesworkstation,OU=training,OU=computers,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com
changetype: moddn
newrdn: joesworkstation
deleteoldrdn: 1                
newsuperior: OU=laptops,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com
```

This worked quite well and kept all the values of the attributes of the computer object in tact as well.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on LDAP Server Implementation an LDIF should be something like:

```
dn: CN=joesworkstation,OU=training,OU=computers,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com
changetype: moddn 
newsuperior: OU=laptops,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com
# remove old RDN entry
deleteoldrdn: 1
```

There could be restraints on such activities.
Perform due diligence.

There maybe [better methods for Microsoft Active Directory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731825(v=ws.11).aspx). 
-jim

Comment: Tried that LDIF format and received the following error:

`ldapmodify: expecting "newrdn:" but saw "newsuperior:" (line 3, entry "CN=joesworkstation,OU=training,OU=computers,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com")`

Comment: The exact order of elements for `changetype: moddn` is defined in [RFC 2849](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2849.txt). Also, there may exist attribute types  like memberOf which need [special treatment](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Export-and-Import-content-7234f521).